# Still seeing seasonal pattern in ACF plot after multiple differencing

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I've seen a couple of questions asked here about seasonality "left over" (so to speak) after differencing like [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/354737/even-after-seasonality-adjustment-seasonality-still-remains-why) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62231/can-monthly-seasonality-adjusted-data-still-exhibit-seasonality), but unfortunately those answers don't help my situation.

I have ~ 17000 hourly observations which seem to exhibit daily (frequency=24) and weekly (frequency=168) seasonalities, as well as general nonstationary unit root (d=1).  But even after removing these three components I'm still seeing troubling autocorrelation at lag 24 and 168.  I'm not sure if even may have overdifferenced.  Below are the ACF plots:

*Original Data ACF*

[image]

*First-Order Differencing*

[image]

*After seasonal difference of 168*

[image]

*After seasonal difference of 24*

[image]

The data is taken from [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/marklvl/bike-sharing-dataset) in the hour.csv file, using the first 8645 observations to model the `cnt` variable.

I'm at a loss at how to resolve this.  I'm trying to make 8 hour ahead forecasts.  Can anyone please help?